# Windows WMI - Getting multiple MAC addresses

Tags: c++, c, windows, wmi, mac-address

I am using the following function and query to retrieve the network adapter's MAC address :

```
QueryValue( pService, L"SELECT MACAddress FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter", L"MACAddress", NetMacAddress, bufferLength );
```

But i don't know how to specify which card i want to get the address of. Is there a way to get the MAC address of every card on the computer (assuming they are activated and all that) using WMI ? Or using something else ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Without WMI you can simply use something like this...

```
unsigned long ulLen = 0;
    IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES* p_adapAddress = NULL;

    DWORD dwRetValue = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, 0, NULL, p_adapAddress,&ulLen);
    if(dwRetValue == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        p_adapAddress = (PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES)malloc(ulLen);
        if(p_adapAddress)
        {
            dwRetValue = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, 0, NULL, p_adapAddress,&ulLen);
            if(dwRetValue == NO_ERROR)
            {                                                   
                IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES* p_adapAddressAux = p_adapAddress;
                do
                {
                    // Get the value of the p_adapAddressAux.PhysicalAddress

                }
                while(p_adapAddressAux != NULL);                                                    
            }

            free(p_adapAddress);
        }
    }
```